# SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow gets cancled with 401 error in top level site and works perfectly in subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a workflow in SPD 2013 to send and meeting Invite Email to attendee in Calendar list. Workflow immediately gets canceled `with 401 Error` even if there is only single Log activity (I have removed Email activity).

When I create any workflow in subsite with the same user it works perfectly. Subsite Inherits the Permission so No permission issue. I am running workflow with Full control access user

I have tried the following,

1. Restarting Workflow manager service
2. Re-Register site collection with Workflow Manager service
3. Re-publish workflow
4. Tried on another list in the same top level site collection.

Below is the Error.

> HTTP response content could not be read. 'Error while copying content
>   to a stream.'

Please guide in case I am going in some wrong direction.

Thank you.